# limiting entire html text into 2 lines

Tags: html, css, line-breaks

I have various  with dimensions (defined with CSS) `height:50px, width:100px.`
I want the text inside each  to break approximately in half (only if it is too long) and expand the  if necessary, in order to fit in it.

Now, when the text length requires extra space, breaks into 3 or more lines and overflows the , but I don't want neither to hide nor scroll the text.

You can see the code here:

```
CSS:
    div {
        font-size: 20px;
        border: 1px solid;
        width: 100px;
        height: 50px;    
    }
html:
     <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
```

Comment: does it need to be dynamic? or can you add <br> tags if you'd like?

Comment: the text comes from database

Comment: finally I did what you suggested @EricLemos. I added <br> tags while processing the text in PHP. Thank you! But I don't how to give you credit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this with CSS alone. You need to use JavaScript to detect the height and adjust either the font size of the box width accordingly.

Comment: You are right! You cannot do this with CSS alone! I had been searching and testing for this the last 3 days. So, I'm taking new approach to this. I will not use JavaScript, it's easier for me to process the text in PHP, break it in half with br tag and then use white-space:nowrap to expand only in width

Answer (score 0):

This should do the work

```
div {
display: inline-block;
border: 1px solid;
width: 100px;
height: 50px;  
overflow: hidden;
}
```

- [JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/qk5QG/)
- [Another Topic handling this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7238926/limiting-text-to-only-two-lines)

Of course you'd need to alternate the width and height if you have a different or longer text — in this [Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7238926/limiting-text-to-only-two-lines) (as mentioned earlier) multiple solutions are provided (PHP/CSS).

Comment: but i dont want to hide the overflowing text

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10584020/overriding-overflow-hidden/10584273#10584273 Would this be a solution for you? I know that overflow:hidden will hide any child-elements, so this may be something.