# PHP Limit text to two lines & add dots at the end

Tags: php, css

This guy: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7239020/2453678 posted a great answer here: http://jsfiddle.net/imoda/REs2Q/

Basically, if you want a elegant solution, counting the number of characters is out of question, as each letter has different weight.

The question is:

```
span {
    display: inline-block;
    border: black 1px solid;
    width: 200px;
    height: 40px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

How to modify the above code, so at the end, if the string is shortened, three '.' are added?

Comment: There’s `text-overflow`, but [it can only handle one line comfortably](http://jsfiddle.net/rninty/REs2Q/249/).

Answer (score 1):

I've coded a simple function in PHP.

```
function limit_text($input, $n){
    $array = preg_split('~\R+~', $input);       // Split by newline(s)
    $array = array_slice($array, 0, $n);        // Get the first n parts
    $output = implode('<br>', $array) . '...';  // Implode and add some dots
    return $output;
}
```

Here's how you use it:

```
$str = 'span {
    display: inline-block;
    border: black 1px solid;
    width: 200px;
    height: 40px;
    overflow: hidden;
}';

echo '<pre>' . limit_text($str, 2); . '</pre>';
```

Comment: Outstanding, but, how can I limit the line width?

Comment: @ShadowHero Well I'm re-reading your question and I'm wondering why you tagged it as "PHP" ? Maybe you meant CSS ? As for the line width, that's possible, we could limit a line to say 50 characters. But would those 50 + 50 + 50 characters make sense when combined ?

Comment: You are correct, the question is css for sure and maybe php, depending on the way you solve it. As for the line width, I am trying to make it work with pixels, e.g. 150px.

Comment: @ShadowHero Then just forget about PHP. Since it all depends on the font type, size, style etc...

Comment: Is what I am trying to do possible?

Comment: I mean, if it's impossible with php, the only other way is css. But css doesn't add characters...

Comment: @ShadowHero [Sure you can](http://jsfiddle.net/F5dmS/), but not in your case ... Well at the moment I don't have a solution for you ..,